# What should I do when I encounter unkown compiler error using "meson setup builddir"?

Tags: windows, meson-build

I am trying to install `gst-rtsp-server` library by running `meson.build`.
To do so, I installed meson from pip3, and tried to build the library using

```
meson setup builddir
```

But then the error message that I received is,

```
**meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['icl'], ['cl'], ['cc'], ['gcc'], ['clang'], ['clang-cl'], ['pgcc']]
The following exception(s) were encountered:
Running "icl " gave "[WinError 2] Cannot find designated file"
...**
```

It was the same message for all above compilers.
What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're on windows, and you don't have any compilers in your path. IF you're wanting to use the Visual Studio compiler (cl), then the easiest way is to open the Visual Studio command prompt, and run Meson from there (I think that the forthcoming meson 0.60 will have an option to discover cl.exe automatically). Other compiler options on Windows are gcc or clang from msys or the older intel icl compiler (not the new oneAPI one)

Comment: Thanks, I used Visual studio cmd to solve the problem, but didn't succeed in building the library :( I've given up on the problem now, but there must be some other way to implement the library.