# Difficulty installing packages with pip

Tags: python, pip, dependencies, setuptools, pypy

I am facing errors when trying to install packages in the pypy environment. This is the error message when I try to install scipy, but I am unable to install any package:

```
C:\Users\anton\Desktop\pypy3.9-v7.3.15-win64>pypy3 -m pip install scipy
Collecting scipy
  Downloading scipy-1.12.0.tar.gz (56.8 MB)
     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     Γò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     Γò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕ΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║ΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║Γ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò║Γ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓò╕Γ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓ     ΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöüΓöü 56.8/56.8 MB 5.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  ├ù Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  Γöé exit code: 1
  Γò░ΓöÇ> [21 lines of output]
      + meson setup C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1ja4tmv2\scipy_9a3d2abfe8f34657add0af6f2e2e38d4 C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1ja4tmv2\scipy_9a3d2abfe8f34657add0af6f2e2e38d4\.mesonpy-lv0h8aw7 -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1ja4tmv2\scipy_9a3d2abfe8f34657add0af6f2e2e38d4\.mesonpy-lv0h8aw7\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.3.1
      Source dir: C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1ja4tmv2\scipy_9a3d2abfe8f34657add0af6f2e2e38d4
      Build dir: C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1ja4tmv2\scipy_9a3d2abfe8f34657add0af6f2e2e38d4\.mesonpy-lv0h8aw7
      Build type: native build
      Project name: scipy
      Project version: 1.12.0
      WARNING: Failed to activate VS environment: Could not find C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe

      ..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['icl'], ['cl'], ['cc'], ['gcc'], ['clang'], ['clang-cl'], ['pgcc']]
      The following exception(s) were encountered:
      Running `icl ""` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `cc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `gcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `clang --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `clang-cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `pgcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

      A full log can be found at C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1ja4tmv2\scipy_9a3d2abfe8f34657add0af6f2e2e38d4\.mesonpy-lv0h8aw7\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

├ù Encountered error while generating package metadata.
Γò░ΓöÇ> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.0.1 -> 23.3.2
[notice] To update, run: pypy3.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

C:\Users\anton\Desktop\pypy3.9-v7.3.15-win64>pypy3 -m pip install -U setuptools
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\anton\desktop\pypy3.9-v7.3.15-win64\lib\site-packages (65.5.0)
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached setuptools-69.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (819 kB)
Installing collected packages: setuptools
  Attempting uninstall: setuptools
    Found existing installation: setuptools 65.5.0
    Uninstalling setuptools-65.5.0:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-65.5.0
Successfully installed setuptools-69.0.3

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.0.1 -> 23.3.2
[notice] To update, run: pypy3.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

I get the same error regardless of the package I am trying to install.

I have tried updating pip and setuptools and changed the Pypy version from Python 3.10 to 3.9 because I read that using Python 3.10 may be causing the errors, but I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The PyPy team recommends you use precompiled packages from conda rather than trying to pip-install from source. You can read more about that in our blog post https://www.pypy.org/posts/2022/11/pypy-and-conda-forge.html.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output, the command is failing because pip is trying to call compilers that are not installed, specifically `icl`, `cl`, `cc`, `gcc`,`clang`,  `clang-cl`, and `pgcc`.

Are you invoking this command in a Visual Studio terminal? Try to do it in a regular command line.

[A similar question with a relevant answer. The answer here provides a solution using the Visual Studio command prompt.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69624330/what-should-i-do-when-i-encounter-unkown-compiler-error-using-meson-setup-build)

However painstaking, you could also try manually installing the aforementioned compilers and ensure they are on your PATH.