# Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error

Tags: python, module

pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
Using cached numpy-1.26.4.tar.gz (15.8 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Installing backend dependencies ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [21 lines of output]
+ C:\Users\Ya Zahra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\python.exe C:\Users\Ya Zahra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9k0yru47\numpy_aa35ee8d6f314c8383668c5ac8a97aef\vendored-meson\meson\meson.py setup C:\Users\Ya Zahra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9k0yru47\numpy_aa35ee8d6f314c8383668c5ac8a97aef C:\Users\Ya Zahra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9k0yru47\numpy_aa35ee8d6f314c8383668c5ac8a97aef.mesonpy-0_r_213r -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=C:\Users\Ya Zahra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9k0yru47\numpy_aa35ee8d6f314c8383668c5ac8a97aef.mesonpy-0_r_213r\meson-python-native-file.ini
The Meson build system
Version: 1.2.99
Source dir: C:\Users\Ya Zahra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9k0yru47\numpy_aa35ee8d6f314c8383668c5ac8a97aef
Build dir: C:\Users\Ya Zahra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9k0yru47\numpy_aa35ee8d6f314c8383668c5ac8a97aef.mesonpy-0_r_213r
Build type: native build
Project name: NumPy
Project version: 1.26.4
WARNING: Failed to activate VS environment: Could not find C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe

```
  ..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['icl'], ['cl'], ['cc'], ['gcc'], ['clang'], ['clang-cl'], ['pgcc']]
  The following exception(s) were encountered:
  Running `icl ""` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `cc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `gcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `clang --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `clang-cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `pgcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
 
  A full log can be found at C:\Users\Ya Zahra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9k0yru47\numpy_aa35ee8d6f314c8383668c5ac8a97aef\.mesonpy-0_r_213r\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

I wanted to install the numpy module when I encountered the following error. Not only this module but all modules are facing this problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69624330/what-should-i-do-when-i-encounter-unkown-compiler-error-using-meson-setup-build